# Use of URLs in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to prettify this URL in the output, how can i do that?

```
var msg = beasts[loc.beast_id] + "! Left "+dateFormat(timeToDespawn, "MM:ss")+" Link " + " https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/"+loc.latitude+","+loc.longitude+" ";
```

The word "Link" should directly link to this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/"+loc.latitude+","+loc.longitude+"
```

is this possible, and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your output? Html? Console? Alert? Something else?

Comment: I output it to Slack, Webhook

Comment: What do you mean by "prettify this URL"?

Comment: By prettify, i mean i want not to output the complete URL but i want the word 'Link' to be clickable

Comment: It depends on the output type Slack allows. If you can use HTML, then declare `a` tag over the link, putting the same link in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to output to HTML, you would create your link like this:

```
var msg = "<a href='https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/" + String(loc.latitude) + "," + String(loc.longitude) + "'>Link</a>";
```

You would use this to output it to your HTML page:

```
$('#foo').html(msg);
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v0L9z1L/).